# Taking MySQL database Back up Using Zoc terminal (Linux server)

Tags: mysql, database, linux

My Application uses Mysql database and is hosted on linux server, and I am using Zoc terminal from my window system to connect to mysql Db. I am trying to backup mysql database using mysql dump through Zoc terminal, however its says:  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax.
Anyone, who could help me..

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the command you are executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Zoc terminal, however dumping a database is fairly easy through command line.

```
mysqldump -u user -p database > database.sql
```

There is also the --all-databases trigger as well.